# Checking if a function touches or crosses 0 in an interval

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, roots

I have some arbitrary, but continuous function $y = f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$. For this function I can compute the function itself, as well as any higher-order partial derivatives.

If I were to sample this function on a grid, is it possible to detect if $ f(x_1, x_2, ... x_n) \leq 0 $ somewhere in a given grid cell, using only information available at the cell vertices?

For example, let's take $f(x_1, x_2) = {x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 - 1$. $f(x_1, x_2) \leq 0 $ when ${x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 \leq 1 $. If I were to sample the function at the points (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1) and (1, 1), I would find that all points are positive, but by looking at the derivatives of the function, I can tell that it has crossed an inflection point and thus I should explore that region with a finer resolution.

I am wondering if there is a generalizable property in $n$ dimensions that would allow me to algorithmically detect cells in a grid that may contain values smaller or equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general.

If the function takes on opposite signs at any two corners of a grid cell then the intermediate value theorem guarantees a root in the cell (even in the interior, with a little more argument).

But you can clearly construct a function as smooth as you wish that's $1$ at all the corners with arbitrary partial derivatives there that vanishes (or never vanishes) inside the grid.

Comment: From doing some reading, I think I can refine my original question. The function I am dealing with is a smooth hypersurface.

Additionally, for my application I can relax what I am looking for a little bit. I am looking for cells that may contain a root, rather than if they truly detect a root. This means that it would be acceptable to have false-positives, that means a cell maybe having a root, or alternatively detect if a cell is guaranteed to not contain a root.

Comment: That's not a lot more useful information. If you can reason from the context that the function is increasing in some directions or that it's convex then you can use the derivatives at the corners to make probabie inferences. They will be more reliable the smaller the grid cells.

Comment: Thank you for your response! As a workable alternative, would it be reasonable to produce a taylor expansion/approximation of my function within a given grid cell, then check if any real roots/solutions exist within the bounds of the cell? It seems like reducing the problem to a multivariate polynomial would greatly simplify things.

Comment: Whether any particular strategy works in your application is not a mathematical question. The answer depends on your context. Try your Taylor expansion idea on some representative examples and see if the results are useful.